# C# unneccesary enter while using voice recognition

Tags: c#, readline, speech

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Brain b = new Brain();
        b.start();
    }
}
public class Map
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
    public Map(string key, string value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
public class Ears
{
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine ears;
    public Ears(List<Map> knowledge, EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs> onRecognise, EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs> onReject)
    {

        this.ears = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        Choices commands = new Choices();
        foreach (var item in knowledge)
        {
            commands.Add(item.key);
        }
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        ears.LoadGrammar(grammar);
        ears.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        ears.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        ears.SpeechRecognized += onRecognise;
        ears.SpeechRecognitionRejected += onReject;

    }
    public void stop()
    {
        ears.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
    }
    public void start()
    {
        ears.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
}
public class Brain
{
    protected List<Map> commands;
    protected List<Map> answers;

    private readonly Ears ears;
    public Brain()
    {
        commands = new List<Map>();
        commands.Add(new Map("list",""));
        commands.Add(new Map("somethingElse","someValue"));
        ears = new Ears(commands, onRecognized, onRejected);
    }
    private void onRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        terminateCommands(new Map(e.Result.Text.Trim().ToLower(), null));
    }
    public void start() {
        while (true) {
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer!="")
            {
                terminateCommands(new Map(answer, null));
            }
        }
    }
    private void onRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void terminateCommands(Map cmd) {
        Console.WriteLine("need user input");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("need user input again");
        var answer2 = Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

The 'list' method works just fine (called by terminateCommands), if I use my keyboard. So terminateCommands is called from the 'start' method. However, if I use VoiceRecognition (basic Mycrosoft.Speech), and terminateCommands is called from the eventHandler, every time, when the list method needs a user input, I have to press Enter, write sg, and then press Enter again. It seems like that there's another Console.ReadLine() before every Console.ReadLine() in the 'list' method. 
ears.stop() just stops the voice recognition.
Map is a class, containing 2 strings(value,key).
 I'm kinda confused. Any idea?

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down a bit? That's a lot of code, most of which won't be causing the problem. That saves us the time of having to do it for you. :)

Comment: I narrowed it down a bit. The problem occurs with every Console.ReadLine() in the function when it's called from the VoiceRecognize-Event handler. It works fine if it's called from any other function which does not involve voice recognition.

Comment: I guess what I was asking for is a [MCVE] so I can copy/paste it into an IDE and get straight to work helping you, without additional preparation required. Remember we get thousands of questions per day so you are competing for our time. :) Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  This is as minimalistic as I could be. Copy Pastable. speech reference is needed tho. so if onRecognised calls terminateCommands, every Console.ReadLine() is being called 2x, if it's being called from 'start', it works like charm. - @AsteroidsWithWings

Comment: Okay so the problem goes away when you don't use the Speech module? Very weird! Not sure I can explain that.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. It's when the EventHandler calls the terminateCommands function, the Console.Readline() in the start function is still "alive", cause the Voice Recognize is Asynchronous.....?  So I guess the start func is still running, even though the other function has been called. Does it make sense in C#? @AsteroidsWithWings